# Call base class constructor in multi file project

Tags: c++, oop

How do I call the construtor from the base class in a derived class using multi-file program.

IE: How would I split this into a structure where I have four files. Person.h, Person.cpp, Student.h, and Student.cpp.

```
class Person
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Person() { setName(""); }
    Person(string pName) { setName(pName); }
    void setName(string pName) { name = pName; }
    string getName() { return name; }
};
class Student:public Person
{
private:
    Discipline major;
    Person *advisor;
public:
    Student(string sname, Discipline d, Person *adv)
    : Person(sname)
    {
        major = d;
        advisor = adv;
    }
    void setMajor(Discipline d) { major = d; }
    Discipline getMajor() { return major; }
    void setAdvisor(Person *p) { advisor = p; }
    Person *getAdvisor() { return advisor; }
};
```

I would like it to look like this:
Person.h

```
class Person
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Person(); 
    Person(string);
    void setName(string)
    string getName()
};
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
Person::Person() { setName(""); }
Person::Person(string pName) { setName(pName); }
void Person::setName(string pName) { name = pName; }
string Person::getName() { return name; }
```

Student.h

```
class Student:public Person
{
private:
    Discipline major;
    Person *advisor;
public:
    Student(string, Discipline, Person)//call Base class constructor here or .cpp?

    void setMajor(Discipline d) ;
    Discipline getMajor() ;
    void setAdvisor(Person *p) ;
    Person *getAdvisor() ;
};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "Person.h"
Student::Student(string sname, Discipline d, Person *adv)//Call Base class construcotr
{
    major = d;
    advisor = adv;
}
void Student::setMajor(Discipline d) { major = d; }
Discipline Student::getMajor() { return major; }
void Student::setAdvisor(Person *p) { advisor = p; }
Person* Student::getAdvisor() { return advisor; }
};
```

Comment: This has exactly nothing to with file layout, since at time of definition the base class is _always_ available. What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your base `constructor` in Student.cpp when you define `Student::Student()`

```
Student::Student(string sname, Discipline d, Person *adv)//Call Base class construcotr
: Person(sname)  // <<<<< here
{
    major = d;
    advisor = adv;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before and received the following error: "xxx" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of "type"

Comment: Maybe your include guard excludes it away? you don't need to `include "Person.h"` in Student.cpp again as you have include it in Student.h

Comment: the xxx in my code is "Account."  My actual problem is with a more complicated scenario for an bank account app.  I posted a simpler question not to bore you guys with pages of code in multiple files :)